# Как сделать анимацию для слайдера на css?

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Привет!
Как можно сделать анимацию для слайдера на css, переключение осуществляется стрелками, слайды должны смещать друг друга.
Сами слайды подгружаются аяксом. Сейчас загвоздка в стилях. 
Пробовал через keyframes, но не вышло как нужно.
Слайдер выезжающий сверху, получает класс top, слайдер снизу, bottom.
Какими стилями это можно сделать?

Пример как должно быть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для такого перехода лучше использовать `transition: top .3s`, хотя анимировать лучше не положение а `transform`

Comment: а можете пример показать? Т.е. этот вариант без кейфреймов? И анимация через top?

Comment: Да, без кейфреймов, обычная линейная анимация. Вы бы добавили что у вас получилось. Логика в том что когда у верхнего нет класса top, то css в нем `top: -100vh`, когда добавляете класс top, то `top: 0`

Comment: Достаточно много переносить надо. Но я логику понял. Сейчас пробую.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev вынеси в ответы пожалуйста свое сообщение. Что бы отметить можно было.